# Backbone.js and jQuery Mobile, function everytime a view is loaded

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a 4 page jquery mobile/backbone.js app.  I want to run a function to populate some inputs with an ajax call everytime a certain page is loaded.  I know I can do the call on render but that is only when the app or page initially loads and won't run again unless it is refreshed.

The view looks something like this:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'text!templates/default/parent.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, parentTemplate) {
var defaultView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
  $(this.el).html(parentTemplate);
            this.render();
},

events: {
  'click #busNext': 'showTarget'
},

render: function() {
  this.setValidator();
  return this;
}

});
return new defaultView;
});
```

Comment: Why don't you bind to the `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow` [events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here render calls onces,
If you wanted to call them again based on some condition then,
You have to call render method. Like.

```
this.render();
```

It will execute render code again and again as you wish.